# Bash function to find newest file matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash, I would like to create a function that returns the filename of the newest file that matches a certain pattern.  For example, I have a directory of files like:

```
Directory/
   a1.1_5_1
   a1.2_1_4
   b2.1_0
   b2.2_3_4
   b2.3_2_0
```

I want the newest file that starts with 'b2'.  How do I do this in bash?  I need to have this in my `~/.bash_profile` script.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified for more answer hints. The sorting is the key step to get your newest file

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The `ls` command has a parameter `-t` to sort by time. You can then grab the first (newest) with `head -1`.

```
ls -t b2* | head -1
```

But beware: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

My personal opinion: parsing `ls` is dangerous when the filenames can contain funny characters like spaces or newlines.

If you can guarantee that the filenames will not contain funny characters (maybe because you are in control of how the files are generated) then parsing `ls` is quite safe.

If you are developing a script which is meant to be run by many people on many systems in many different situations then do not parse `ls`.

Here is how to do it safe:

```
unset -v latest
for file in "$dir"/*; do
  [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
done
```

for more explanation read [How can I find the latest (newest, earliest, oldest) file in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

also [What is the difference between test, single square bracket and double square bracket ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: Note to others: if you are doing this for a directory, you would add the -d option to ls, like this 'ls -td <pattern> | head -1'

Comment: The [parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) link says not to do this and recommends the methods in [BashFAQ 99](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099). I'm looking for a 1-liner rather than something bullet-proof to include in a script, so I'll continue to parse ls unsafely like @lesmana.

Comment: @Eponymous: If you're looking for a one liner without using the fragile `ls`, `printf "%s\n" b2* | head -1` will do it for you.

Comment: @Eponymous In the question the "newest" file is implied by the actual file name (increasing version numbers) so lexical ordering is correct here. Relying on the modification timestamp is less reliable here since files can be touched.

Comment: @DavidOngaro The question does not say that the filenames are version numbers. This is about modification times. Even with the filename assumption `b2.10_5_2` kills this solution.

Comment: @Eponymous: It also doesn't say anything about "modification times", so what "newest" means is up to interpretation. Of course if one orders version numbers lexicographically one has to consider the appropriate number of 0 prefixes beforehand depending how big they'll get.

Comment: @DavidOngaro shouldn't that be `tail -1`, not `head`? Head will give you the lexically oldest, won't it?

Comment: @Fadecomic: Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed the lexically newest should be at the end while `ls -t` has the file with the newest timestamp at the top.

Comment: Your one liner is giving me right answer, but the "right" way is actually giving me the *oldest* file. Any idea why?

Comment: As for the security of parsing *`ls`*: if you can verify that the files do not have any abnormal characters i.e. you yourself made them and you know it cannot be changed then it can be considered 'safe'. But as soon as you introduce other uses it is another matter entirely. And even then: what if you didn't foresee something? So it's a choice one has to make but a choice that requires awareness. Which ultimately is a huge problem in our world.

Comment: @Fadecomic That or using the *`-r`* option to *`ls`*.

Comment: A nice "add-on" for log files: with something like this `ls -t b2* | head -1 | xargs tail -f`, shows the an auto-refresh tail

Comment: The second variant ("how to do it right") did not work for me, it gave me "vmlinuz.old" as a result. I used `file=$(ls -t *.prg | head -1)` in the end, when I quote the filename in further usage (`"$file"`), it works fine even with spaces in filenames.

Comment: This will run into "argument list too long" if the wildcard matches too many files. The second solution avoids that, but suffers from [broken quoting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: In `[[ $file -nt $latest ]]`, the first time `$latest` will be empty. How does that not break?

Comment: the double square bracket is different from the single square bracket. in `[[ $file -nt $latest ]]` if `$latest` is empty then `$file` is newer by default. see here for more explanation http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 34):

The combination of `find` and `ls` works well for

- filenames without newlines
- not very large amount of files
- not very long filenames

**The solution:**

```
find . -name "my-pattern" -print0 |
    xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t |
    head -1
```

**Let's break it down:**

With `find` we can match all interesting files like this:

```
find . -name "my-pattern" ...
```

then using `-print0` we can pass all filenames safely to the `ls` like this:

```
find . -name "my-pattern" -print0 | xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t
```

additional `find` search parameters and patterns can be added here

```
find . -name "my-pattern" ... -print0 | xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t
```

`ls -t` will sort files by modification time (newest first) and print it one at a line. You can use `-c` to sort by creation time. **Note**: this will break with filenames containing newlines.

Finally `head -1` gets us the first file in the sorted list.

**Note:** `xargs` use system limits to the size of the argument list. If this size exceeds, `xargs` will call `ls` multiple times. This will break the sorting and probably also the final output. Run

```
xargs  --show-limits
```

to check the limits on you system.

**Note 2:** use `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "my-pattern" -print0` if you don't want to search files through subfolders.

**Note 3:** As pointed out by @starfry - `-r` argument for `xargs` is preventing the call of `ls -1 -t`, if no files were matched by the `find`. Thank you for the suggesion.

Comment: This is better than the ls based solutions, as it works for directories with extremely many files, where ls chokes.

Comment: `find . -name "my-pattern" ... -print0` gives me `find: paths must precede expression: \`...'`

Comment: Oh! `...` stands for "more parameters". Just omit it, if you don't need it.

Comment: I found that this can return a file that does not match the pattern if there are no files that do match the pattern. It happens because find passes nothing to xargs which then invokes ls with no file lists, causing it to work on all files. The solution is to add `-r` to the xargs command-line which tells xargs not to run its command-line if it receives nothing on its standard input.

Comment: @starfry thank you! Nice catch. I added `-r` to the answer.

Comment: As others have mentioned, this answer is incorrect. `find: paths must precede expression: `...'`. Please edit your answer to remove the incorrect code. Don't just append more text. That just adds noise.

Comment: @Cerin fixed it. The tripple dots "..." stud here as a placeholder for "more parameters" and shouldn't be executed as a part of the command. See the third comment above. Removed it to prevent confusion about it.

Comment: This is still incorrect if you have many files, because `xargs` will then invoke `ls -t` multiple times, and `head -1` will get the first file from the first invocation of `ls -t`, not the oldest overall. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320196/why-does-find-return-different-sorted-results-when-passed-the-current-directory

Comment: @tripleee This is exactly, what I described in the "Note" section. It is still useful and relatively simple solution for most cases.

Comment: The note doesn't really tell beginners that this is buggy in its current form, and obviously offers no remedy.

Comment: @tripleee The first sentence is "The combination of find and ls works well for ... not very large amount of files". IMHO It defines the frame of the application of this solution pretty well. In bash you most of the time have to trade between practical 95% solutions and very involved 100% solutions. My solution is modular, showing beginners how to solve not only this particular problem, but also a lot of other problems by combining tools, like find and ls using args and print0.

Answer (score 13):

This is a possible implementation of the required Bash function:

```
# Print the newest file, if any, matching the given pattern
# Example usage:
#   newest_matching_file 'b2*'
# WARNING: Files whose names begin with a dot will not be checked
function newest_matching_file
{
    # Use ${1-} instead of $1 in case 'nounset' is set
    local -r glob_pattern=${1-}

    if (( $# != 1 )) ; then
        echo 'usage: newest_matching_file GLOB_PATTERN' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # To avoid printing garbage if no files match the pattern, set
    # 'nullglob' if necessary
    local -i need_to_unset_nullglob=0
    if [[ ":$BASHOPTS:" != *:nullglob:* ]] ; then
        shopt -s nullglob
        need_to_unset_nullglob=1
    fi

    newest_file=
    for file in $glob_pattern ; do
        [[ -z $newest_file || $file -nt $newest_file ]] \
            && newest_file=$file
    done

    # To avoid unexpected behaviour elsewhere, unset nullglob if it was
    # set by this function
    (( need_to_unset_nullglob )) && shopt -u nullglob

    # Use printf instead of echo in case the file name begins with '-'
    [[ -n $newest_file ]] && printf '%s\n' "$newest_file"

    return 0
}
```

It uses only Bash builtins, and should handle files whose names contain newlines or other unusual characters.

Comment: You could you use `nullglob_shopt=$(shopt -p nullglob)` and then later `$nullglob` to put back `nullglob` how it was before.

Comment: The suggestion by @gniourf_gniourf to use $(shopt -p nullglob) is a good one.  I generally try to avoid using command substitution (`$()` or backticks) because it is slow, particularly under Cygwin, even when the command only uses builtins.  Also, the subshell context in which the commands get run can sometimes cause them to behave in unexpected ways.  I also try to avoid storing commands in variables (like `nullglob_shopt`) because very bad things can happen if you get the value of the variable wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the attention to details that can lead to obscure failure when overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: I love that you went for a more unique way to solve the problem! It's a certainty that in Unix/Linux there is more than one way to 'skin the *`cat`*!'. Even if this takes more work it has the benefit of showing people concepts. Have a +1!

Answer (score 9):

Use the find command.

Assuming you're using GNU find, you can use `-printf '%T+ %p\n'` for file timestamp value.

```
find . -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Example:

```
find ~/Downloads -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

For a more useful script, see the **find-latest** script here: https://github.com/l3x/helpers

Comment: to work with file names that contains spaces change cut -d'  ' -f2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ...

Comment: The version of Bash is unimportant. You need to have GNU `find` because the `-printf` option is non-standard (so typically, out of the box, this will only work on Linux).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `stat` with a file glob and a decorate-sort-undecorate with the file time added on the front:

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%N" b2* | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2-
```

---

As stated in comments, the best cross platform solution may be with a Python, Perl, Ruby script.

For such things, I tend to use Ruby since it is very awk like in the ease of writing small, throw away scripts yet has the power of Python or Perl right from the command line.

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -e '
# index [0] for oldest and [-1] for newest
newest=Dir.glob("*").
    reject { |f| File.directory?(f)}.
    sort_by { |f| File.birthtime(f) rescue File.mtime(f) 
    }[-1]
p newest'
```

That gets the newest file in the current working directory.

You can also make the glob recursive by using `**/*` in `glob` or limit to matched files with `b2*`, etc

Comment: nope. "stat: cannot read file system information for '%m%t%N': No such file or directory"

Comment: I think this might be for the Mac/FreeBSD version of `stat`, if I'm remembering its options correctly. To get similar output on other platforms, you could use `stat -c $'%Y\t%n' b2* | sort -rn  | head -n1 | cut -f2-`

Comment: With "other platforms" you probably mean Linux. There are other platforms still which require different options, or, in the wrorst case, don't easily provide this level of granularity of control over the behavior of `stat`. If you need a portable solution, paradoxically, maybe write a Perl or Python script.

Answer (score 6):

**A Bash function to find the newest file under a directory matching a pattern**

```
#1.  Make a bash function:
newest_file_matching_pattern(){ 
    find $1 -name "$2" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1 -t | head -1  
} 
 
#2. Setup a scratch testing directory: 
mkdir /tmp/files_to_move;
cd /tmp/files_to_move;
touch file1.txt;
touch file2.txt; 
touch foobar.txt; 
 
#3. invoke the function: 
result=$(newest_file_matching_pattern /tmp/files_to_move "file*") 
printf "result: $result\n"
```

Prints:

```
result: /tmp/files_to_move/file2.txt
```

**Or if brittle bash parlor tricks subcontracting to python interpreter is more your angle, this does the same thing:**

```
#!/bin/bash 
 
function newest_file_matching_pattern { 
python - <<END 
import glob, os, re  
print(sorted(glob.glob("/tmp/files_to_move/file*"), key=os.path.getmtime)[0]); 
END 
} 
 
result=$(newest_file_matching_pattern) 
printf "result: $result\n"
```

Prints:

```
result: /tmp/files_to_move/file2.txt
```

Comment: That's [broken quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) but also more fatally [broken for large directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320196/why-does-find-return-different-sorted-results-when-passed-the-current-directory)

Comment: @tripleee All excellent bash tips and links.  Cringe code from 3 years ago made less bad.

Answer (score 4):

Unusual filenames (such as a file containing the valid `\n` character can wreak havoc with this kind of parsing. Here's a way to do it in Perl:

```
perl -le '@sorted = map {$_->[0]} 
                    sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} 
                    map {[$_, -M $_]} 
                    @ARGV;
          print $sorted[0]
' b2*
```

That's a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) used there.

Comment: May the schwartz be with you!

Comment: this answer may work but i wouldn't trust it given the poor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For googlers:

`ls -t | head -1`

- `-t` sorts by last modification datetime
- `head -1` only returns the first result

([Don't use in production](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

Answer (score 0):

Combine `find`, `stat`, `sort`, `cut` and `tail`.

1. `find` files `-type f` (matching name `-name 'b2*'`)
2. `xargs stat` stat those files printing `%Y` seconds since epoch and `%n` the filename
3. `sort` that
4. `cut` field `-f` 2 onwards `2-` (tab separated)
5. `tail` the last `-n 1` of that to get the newest file

Works in all shells and POSIX compatible systems (AFAIK)

```bash
tab=$(printf '\t');
find . -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 stat --format "%Y$tab%n" |
  sort |
  cut -f 2- |
  tail -n 1
```

Feel free to substitute "$tab" for a literal tab character, it won't work on SO.

OP asked to filter the names of files starting with `b2`, so that would be

```bash
tab=$(printf '\t');
find . -type f -name 'b2*' -print0 |
  xargs -0 stat --format "%Y$tab%n" |
  sort |
  cut -f 2- |
  tail -n 1
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a much more efficient way of achieving this. Consider the following command:

```
find . -cmin 1 -name "b2*"
```

This command finds the latest file produced exactly one minute ago with the wildcard search on "b2*". If you want files from the last two days then you'll be better off using the command below:

```
find . -mtime 2 -name "b2*"
```

The "." represents the current directory. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't actually find the "newest file matching pattern"... it just find all the files matching pattern created a minute ago, or modified two days ago.

Comment: This answer was based on the question posed. Also, you can tweak the command to look at the latest file that came in a day or so ago. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: "tweaking" is not the answer. it's like posting this as an answer:  "Just tweak the find command and find the answer depending on what you want to do" .

Comment: Not sure about the unnecessary comment. If you feel like my answer does not substantiate, then please provide proper reason to why my answer doesn't make sense with EXAMPLES. If unable to do so, then please refrain from commenting further.

Comment: Your solution requires you to know *when* the latest file was created.  That was not in the question so no, your answer is not based on the question posed.