# Find newest file in folder via the terminal (seconds apart)

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to extract the newest file in folder.
I tried this:

```
ls -1t | head -1
```

But the problem is, that this command doesn't seem to differentiate in which second the file was created - if multiple files were created in the the same, this command just give the first file in this minute.

Is there a way to make this command more precise?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885934/bash-function-to-find-newest-file-matching-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `T` argument to the options to do that:

```
ls -1tT | head -1
```

See the output when `l` argument is added:

```
ls -tTl

-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel      0 Apr 23 17:54:27 2016 1
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel      0 Apr 23 17:54:19 2016 3 
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel      0 Apr 23 17:54:12 2016 2
```