# How to find the filename of .gz file created latest in the directory with partial filename

Tags: linux, file, awk, find, gzip

In a directory (/var/log ) there are lots of .gz file .i need to get/find the filename of a .gz file(.eg xyz_.gz, xyz1.gz ,xyz2.gz) that was created with latest timestamp (that was newly created in  the directory ) whose partial file name is ("xyz")

Comment: Please show some sample input and sample output in your post in code tags for better understanding of this question.

Comment: This might help: [Bash function to find newest file matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5885934/3776858)

Comment: have a directory /var/log which has files like /xyz_201806240108.gz , /xyz_201806241803.gz , i need to find the file that was last created in directory with partial name starting with xyz * ,using python

Answer (score -1):

You can use `stat` with a file glob:

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%N" /var/log/*.gz | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2-
```

The `%m` is the file time and the `%N` is the file name. That pattern is then used for a decorate-sort-undecorate to find the newest.

You can add `sed` to that to filter file names that have a regex pattern if desired.

Comment: i am using ls -t b2* | head -1 but i need to do this on another directory (/var/log) without changing the working directory which is not working

Comment: Did you try `stat /var/log/*.gz`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ls -ltr xyz*.gz` and have the gz-file with the shortest modification time at the bottom of the listing