# Linux find file over ssh whose filename is partially known

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of files:

```
XX_1
XX_2
XX_3
```

whose numbers keep incrementing every single time I run the program.
I want to find the latest file using a linux command. I tried:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*XX_*" -print
```

but this gives me all the files with XX_. I just want XX_3 and need to save the output that I get using this command to a variable so that I can copy the file. How do I do that?
I tried:

```
var=$(ssh pi@192.168.0.101 ls -1 FlightLog* | sort -t_ -k2 -nr | head -1)
ssh pi@192.168.0.101 sftp "$var"
```

And I got the following error:

```
/Users/ykathur2/bin/GetFile.sh: line 3: var: command not found
ssh: Could not resolve hostname flightlog_88.dat: Name or service not known
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash function to find newest file matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5885934/608639)

Comment: The error indicates you're getting the newest filename (_flightlog_88.dat_). If you're just trying to copy that file to the local host, the second line won't do that. Try `scp pi@192.168.0.101:"$var" .` instead.

Comment: I tried that but I got:

    usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
    [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
    [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
$ ls -1 XX*
XX_1
XX_2
XX_3

$ ls -1 XX* | sort -t_ -k2 -nr | head -1
XX_3
```