# Finding newest file in directory and make a copy

Tags: bash

My goal is to find the newest image in a directory and make a copy of it with a new name.

I've tried using the find command but copying doesn't seem to work

Here is what will return me the most recent image taken

```
lastimage=$(find *.jpg -type f | xargs ls -ltr | tail -n 1)
echo $lastimage
```

Then I've tried this to make a copy of it and call it lastimage.jpg

```
lastimage=`find *.jpg -type f | xargs ls -ltr | tail -n 1` && cp $lastimage /path/to/location/lastimage.jpg
```

I expect to see `lastimage.jpg` in the same directory i called it from. 
My actual result is

```
cp: invalid option -- 'w'
```

Comment: try using  `find` with `stat -c "%Y %n" ` and `sort`

Comment: See [Bash function to find newest file matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5885934/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

If you have [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), with the aid of [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) you could implement a solution like below :

```
while read -rd '' fname
do
 atime=$(stat -c %X "$fname")
 [ "${max:-0}" -le "$atime" ] && max="$atime" && la="$fname"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
cp "${la}" "/path/to/destination/${la##*/}"
```

<sub>**Note:** The `-r` option with`while`  prevents escape sequences from  being interpreted.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can add `awk '{print $NF}'` to your command and it'll work. The problem is that `ls -ltr` returns file information as well as the file names where as you only want the file name. The `awk` command cuts the output of `ls` to only the last column (file names).

```
 lastimage=`find *.jpg -type f | xargs ls -ltr | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n 1` && cp $lastimage /path/to/location/lastimage.jpg
```