# How to find the latest file matching a pattern

Tags: bash, cron

I'm new to this, but I've been asked to write a bash script to SFTP a file from one server to another. The bash script will be run 4 times per day using CRON, just after the file below has been created.
The client's website creates XML files containing orders 4 times per day. Each file is given a new name, with an incremental number.
For example:

```
a_file-01.xml
b_file-01.xml
a_file-02.xml
b_file-02.xml
a_file-03.xml
b_file-03.xml
```

How can I find the newest file (which will also have the highest number)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash function to find newest file matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885934/bash-function-to-find-newest-file-matching-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to just use `ls`.  You can order the files in a directory this way:   `ls -t`.  The newest file is on the top of the list.  So this will work:

```
NEWEST=$( ls -t | head -1 )
```

However, you may want to glob to get your results ( to avoid files that are unintentionally in your directory ):

```
NEWEST=$( ls -t *file*.xml | head -1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark.

Having now got the list, I need to copy/move the latest file to another folder.

I have this code, but I can't get it to work. Testing it as part of a CRON job gives an error.

# get newest file in folder
cd /public_html/uploads/foldername/
NEWEST=$( ls -t | head -1 )

cp /public_html/uploads/foldername/"$NEWEST" /public_html/orders/"$NEWEST"
quit
EOF

My cron is as follows:
30 06 * * * /opt/xmlbackup.sh

Thanks!

Comment: Non-portable as for the security reasons `glob()` must be disabled in the scripts.

Comment: @0andriy, sorry but which is the part that is non-portable ? I would also like to know why glob should be disabled in scripts, so I can correct my own scripts.

Comment: @Jetchisel I was talking about glob, your script much worse.

Comment: Besides the fact of the security impacts, the glob may behave very interesting if the filename contains asterisks. For the starter, make shebangs of your scripts as `#/bin/sh -efu`, second, test your scripts under `dash` — voila, your scripts now in the top 2% correctly written ones (of course after fixing plenty of bugs).

Comment: @0andriy, the question is tagged as bash so why bring up portability? Also folks who insists on using  `-e` should know better what to expect, If you're a fan of `-e` then you deserve whats coming for you...

Comment: `For the starter, make shebangs of your scripts as #/bin/sh -efu` No one in their right mind will advice any one to use that kind of shebang without explaining the (side) effects it might have, so please don't tell others to use it, keep it to your self...

Comment: `your scripts now in the top 2% correctly written ones (of course after fixing plenty of bugs)` Can you show/site where did you get the data of `2% correctly written ones`. I mean where can I find it? Or you're just making things up?