# Why does find return different, sorted results when passed the current directory versus a path?

Tags: shell, find, zsh, ls

I'm attempting to write a shell command returning the most recently modified file.
However, the directory has more files than `ls` can accommodate directly (hence using `find`, which I understand to be the proper solution for piping into other commands anyway).

In doing so, I've encountered a confusing difference between running `find .` in the directory, and passing the directory to find (*i.e.* `find $folder`).

Here is an example:

```bash
➜  echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/zsh
➜  pwd
/Users/aresnick/Downloads
➜  find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -1
./DID_Codebook_2020.pdf
➜  find $(pwd) -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -1
/Users/aresnick/Downloads/Profiles17_MA.pdf
➜  find /Users/aresnick/Downloads -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -1
/Users/aresnick/Downloads/Profiles17_MA.pdf
```

Note that `DID_Codebook_2020.pdf` is not the same file as `Profiles17_MA.pdf`.  **How can I explain why these commands seem to return different results?**

For reference, here is the output of `ls -halt | head -5` in the directory (including the two most recent files which are getting confused here).

```bash
➜ ls -halt | head -5
total 51229416
drwxr-xr-x+   92 aresnick  staff   2.9K Oct 12 10:34 ..
drwx------@ 4033 aresnick  staff   126K Oct 12 10:02 .
-rw-r--r--@    1 aresnick  staff   1.7M Oct 12 10:02 DID_Codebook_2020.pdf
-rw-r--r--@    1 aresnick  staff   470K Oct 12 10:00 Profiles17_MA.pdf
```

Looking more closely *via* `stat`, it appears that the *change* time is in fact newer on `Profiles17_MA.pdf`:

```bash
➜  stat -f "ACCESS-%Sa   CHANGE-%Sc %SN" {DID_Codebook_2020.pdf,Profiles17_MA.pdf}
ACCESS-Oct 12 10:02:14 2020   CHANGE-Oct 12 10:02:08 2020 DID_Codebook_2020.pdf
ACCESS-Oct 12 10:02:14 2020   CHANGE-Oct 12 10:02:10 2020 Profiles17_MA.pdf
```

However, I don't see how this explains why the sorting order would change with `find .` vs. `find ~/Downloads`.

**What gives?**  I have the vague intuition that this may have something to do with the fact that we're looking at inodes' change times, and something about including the directory changes…something.

Thanks in advance!  Note that while I am also interested in solutions to my specific sorting problem, I'm most interested in understanding why the difference occurs.

Comment: @aresnick : I don't think it is important, but for completeness: Your `find` command does not run the internal zsh version of `ls`, but `/usr/bin/ls`.

Comment: @aresnick : For finding out what is going on, I would use the `-halt` options of `ls` in the `find`- version too, and I would also inspect the whole list, not just the head.

Comment: @aresnick : I also suggest that you use the `--verbose` flag on `xargs`, or alternatively use `xargs -0t` instead of just `xargs -0`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the tips; I don't see anything there unfortunately…the output is the same as the independent `ls -halt` option, and adding `-0t` to `xargs` doesn't seem to reveal anything (other than printing out all the files in `~/Downloads`).

Comment: Consider leaving the xargs ls -t out of the equation.  I believe that you are not looking at inconsistent find results but rather the interaction with `xargs ls -t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of `xargs` is to split up command lines which are longer than the system can accommodate. Let's assume for illustration that you have four files and an OS where `ARG_MAX` is just 25 bytes (though in real life it will be on the order of megabytes on modern systems). Then without a path, `xargs` runs

```
ls -t ./a ./b ./c ./d
```

but with full paths, the command line has to be split up into two invocations, so as not to exceed the limit on how long the command line can be:

```
ls -t /path/to/a /path/to/b
ls -t /path/to/c /path/to/d
```

Now of course if `d` is your newest file, `head` will still return the newest file from the first `ls` invocation.

On a system with GNU `find` (Linux etc) use its `-printf` option to format a string where the modification time precedes the file name.

```sh
find . -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\0" |
sort -rnz |
perl -n000 's/^[^\t]+\t//; print; exit'
```

We sort by modification time, then discard the modification time and print just the file name. The null delimiter takes care of handling even file names with newlines in them; this feature in particular is a GNU extension.

If you don't have the GNU utilities, you can use `find -exec stat` with a similar format string; unfortunately, this feature of `stat` is not standardized, either, but it should not be hard to find examples for non-Linux systems like BSD, macOS, etc.

Comment: This is perfect; thank you for clarifying!  Since `stat` was relatively slow, I ended up just installing `gfind` since I'm on OS X.  Thank you very much for the example of the multiple invocations(also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452206/37772)), which I hadn't seen—

Comment: With `find -exec stat -option blah {} +` it should be only marginally slower than `find`, and I guess still slightly faster than with `xargs`.

Comment: As an aside, you should basically never need `$(pwd)` instead of `.` unless you are specifically trying to convert to absolute paths, and pretty much [never use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure— In my experience `gfind` was nearly 100x faste…`gfind` takes ~0.13s and `find` with `stat` took ~11.8s in a directory with 4023 files.  Figures obtained via `time gfind ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name "*.crdownload" -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort -r | head -1 | perl -pe 's/^.+\t//g;'` and `time find . -type f -exec stat -f '%m %N' {} \; | sort -rn | head -1`.

Comment: That's because you use `-exec ... \;` instead of `-exec ... +`

Comment: Of course, you shoud use `\0` with `stat` too ho make the two exactly equivalent.

Comment: Ah, thank you— Sorry!  I didn't realize the difference between those.  That makes sense!  With that change the difference is 3X, 0.328s